# Linear Algebra, meaning of 0 determinant in linear transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, determinant, area

Lets say the area of a figure in $\Bbb R^2$ was $10$. Then after a noninvertible linear transformation from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$, is there enough info to determine the new area? Since its noninvertible, then the matrix determinant must be $0$. What exactly does this mean, is the new area $0$ or is there no change in scaling of the area?

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the determinant describes the scale factor of the linear transformation. In this case scaling by a factor of zero means that the transformed figure will have area zero. No change in the area would be brought about by a matrix with determinant $\pm 1$.

For example, consider the transformation $\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0  \\
0 & 0  \end{array} \right)$, which projects onto the vector $(1, 0)^T$. It has determinant zero and any figure under the transformation will get squished down onto the line through that vector, leaving it with zero area.