# Is The Composition of Two Linear Transformations Invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Assume we have two linear compositions $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ and $S: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. How would I go about proving that $S \circ T$ ( Composition of $S$ and $T$) is an invertible linear transformation

T(x1,x2)=(x1-x2,3x1-2x2)
S(x1,x2)=(2x1+3x2,-x1+x2)

Comment: Check if det(S*T)=0

Comment: If you don't know anything about $S$ and $T$, then this is just not true. If you *do* know something, please add it to your question, so that we could know it as well!

Comment: If $T $ and $S$ are invertible, then $(S\circ T)^{-1}=T^{-1}\circ S^{-1}$

Comment: Hi Tanner, so T and S are indeed invertible in my case. I confirmed this by checking is the det(T) and det(S) are not equal to 0. Can you please explain how the following: (S∘T)−1=T−1∘S−1 proves that S∘T are invertible. Apologies I am a bit rusty with the symbology

Comment: If $T$ and $S$ are invertible, then $T^{-1}\circ S^{-1}$ exists; if you can show that's an inverse of $S\circ T$, then you have shown that $S\circ T$ is invertible

Answer (score 4):

Note that a linear map $T$ is invertible iff $\det T \neq 0$.
Thus, we need to check precisely when $\det(S\circ T) \neq 0$.
However, note that
$$\det(S\circ T) = \det S\cdot\det T.$$

Thus, we get that
$$\begin{align}\det(S\circ T) \neq 0 &\iff \det S\cdot\det T \neq 0\\
& \iff \det S \neq 0 \text{ and } \det T \neq 0
\end{align}$$

Thus, we get that $S \circ T$ is invertible iff $S$ and $T$ are invertible.

---

**Remark.** We crucially used that $S$ and $T$ were linear maps between spaces of the same dimension. (When we wrote $\det(S\circ T) = \det S \cdot \det T$.)
If we were in the situation $S:\Bbb R^m \to \Bbb R^n$ and $T:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$, the same would not be true.

Answer (score 0):

Please check these links:

https://math.mit.edu/classes/18.013A/MathML/chapter04/section02.xhtml
[Linear Algebra, meaning of 0 determinant in linear transformations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/693654/linear-algebra-meaning-of-0-determinant-in-linear-transformations)

If the linear transform is not invertible, it will transform a set of basis vectors into a zero volume due to the columns of the transformation matrix being lin. dependent